# Bound CUDA texture reads zero

Tags: cuda, 2d, textures

I try to read values from a texture and write them back to global memory.
I am sure the writing part works, beause I can put constant values in the kernel and I can see them in the output:

```
__global__ void
bartureKernel( float* g_odata, int width, int height) 
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(x < width && y < height) {
            unsigned int idx = (y*width + x);
            g_odata[idx] = tex2D(texGrad, (float)x, (float)y).x;

    }
}
```

The texture I want to use is a 2D float texture with two channels, so I defined it as:

```
texture<float2, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> texGrad;
```

And the code which calls the kernel initializes the texture with some constant non-zero values:

```
float* d_data_grad = NULL;

cudaMalloc((void**) &d_data_grad, gradientSize * sizeof(float));
CHECK_CUDA_ERROR;

texGrad.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texGrad.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texGrad.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
texGrad.normalized = false;

cudaMemset(d_data_grad, 50, gradientSize * sizeof(float));
CHECK_CUDA_ERROR;

cudaBindTexture(NULL, texGrad, d_data_grad, cudaCreateChannelDesc<float2>(), gradientSize * sizeof(float));

float* d_data_barture = NULL;
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_data_barture, outputSize * sizeof(float));
CHECK_CUDA_ERROR;

dim3 dimBlock(8, 8, 1);
dim3 dimGrid( ((width-1) / dimBlock.x)+1, ((height-1) / dimBlock.y)+1, 1);

bartureKernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0 >>>( d_data_barture, width, height);
```

I know, setting the texture bytes to all "50" doesn't make much sense in the context of floats, but it should at least give me some non-zero values to read.

I can only read zeros though...

Comment: Where and how are you displaying the values which are coming out as zeroes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `cudaBindTexture` to bind your texture to the memory allocated by `cudaMalloc`. In the kernel you are using `tex2D` function to read values from the texture. That is why it is reading zeros.

If you bind texture to linear memory using `cudaBindTexture`, it is read using `tex1Dfetch` inside the kernel.

`tex2D` is used to read only from those textures which are bound to **pitch linear memory** ( which is allocated by `cudaMallocPitch` ) using the function `cudaBindTexture2D`, or those textures which are bound to **cudaArray** using the function `cudaBindTextureToArray`

Here is the basic table, rest you can read from the programming guide:

| **Memory Type** | **Allocated Using** | **Bound Using** | **Read In The Kernel By** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linear Memory | `cudaMalloc` | `cudaBindTexture` | `tex1Dfetch` |
| Pitch Linear Memory | `cudaMallocPitch` | `cudaBindTexture2D` | `tex2D` |
| `cudaArray` | `cudaMallocArray` | `cudaBindTextureToArray` | `tex1D` or `tex2D` |
| 3D `cudaArray` | `cudaMalloc3DArray` | `cudaBindTextureToArray` | `tex3D` |

Answer (score 3):

To add on, access using `tex1Dfetch` is based on integer indexing.
However, the rest are indexed based on floating point, and you have to add `+0.5` to get the exact value you want.

I'm curious why do you create `float` and bind to a `float2` texture? It may give ambiguous results.
`float2` is not 2D `float` texture. It can actually be used for representation of complex number.

```
typedef struct {float x; float y;} float2;
```

I think [this tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/218100902) will help you understand how to use texture memory in CUDA.

The kernel you shown does not benefit much from using texture. however, if utilized properly, by exploiting locality, texture memory can improve the performance by quite a lot. Also, it is useful for interpolation.